# Partial derivative of tensor from Schaum's Outline problem set Chapter 1

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, tensors

Schaums's outline on Tensor Calculus has the following for problem 1.25: Calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\ell}(a_{ijk} x_i x_j x_k)$ given that the $a_{ijk}$ are constants.

Is the following a correct representation of the partial derivative in Summation notation?

$$\delta^i_\ell a_{ijk} x_j x_k + \delta^j_\ell a_{ijk} x_i x_k + \delta^k_\ell a_{ijk} x_i x_j$$

I believe that the $a_{ijk}$ cannot be pulled out because of their dependence on the different Kronecker delta components. If any of this is wrong, please explain.

Comment: I don't have the book on me right now but it looks correct to me. You are also correct that the $a_{ijk}$ cannot be pulled out because at $\ell = i,j,k$ the constant $a_{ijk}$ are all different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\ell}(a_{ijk} x_i x_j x_k)$ given that $a_{ijk}$ are constants is:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\ell}(a_{ijk} x_i x_j x_k) = a_{ijk} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\ell}(x_i x_j x_k)$$

$$= a_{ijk} (\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_\ell} x_j x_k + \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_\ell} x_i x_k + \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_\ell} x_i x_j)$$

Given that $\frac{\partial x_p}{\partial x_q} = \delta_{pq}$,

$$= a_{ijk} (\delta_{i\ell} x_j x_k + \delta_{j\ell} x_i x_k +\delta_{k\ell} x_i x_j)$$

Redistributing leads to

$$= a_{ijk} \delta_{i\ell} x_j x_k + a_{ijk} \delta_{j\ell} x_i x_k + a_{ijk} \delta_{k\ell} x_i x_j$$

$$= a_{\ell jk} x_j x_k + a_{i \ell k} x_i x_k + a_{ij\ell} x_i x_j$$

Rewriting indices (both free and dummy) for independent terms leads to

$$= a_{ij\ell} x_i x_j + a_{i\ell j} x_i x_j + a_{k\ell ij} x_i x_j$$

$$= (a_{ij\ell} + a_{i\ell j} + a_{\ell ij}) x_i x_j$$